# Attribute error:'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

I tried to run a python script for getting the coordinate system of a feature/shapefile as follow

```
>>> import arcpy  
>>> from arcpy import env  
>>> env.workspace="D:\data"  
>>> fc="river.shp"  
>>> dsc=arcpy.Describe(fc)  
>>> dsc.spatialReference.Name  
>>> print dsc
```

i'm getting following error at line 5

> Attributeerror:'NoneType' object has no attribute Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing this line:

```
env.workspace="D:\data"
```

with:

```
env.workspace=r"D:\data"
```

or

```
env.workspace="D:/data"
```

or

```
env.workspace="D:\\data"
```

should enable it to work but, if you are using ArcGIS 10.1 like me, you will also need to use ".Name" without the capital i.e. ".name".

My working test code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace=r"C:\temp"
fc="test2.shp"
dsc=arcpy.Describe(fc)
print dsc.spatialReference.name
```

returns this (as expected):

> GCS_GDA_1994

Comment: I tried in that way also, but no change in error

Comment: Does your shapefile have a *.prj ? An undefined coordinate system would probably explain the error you are seeing which I do not.

Comment: yes it had .prj file. if i tried to run the above code i'm getting an Attributeerror that: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Name'

Comment: if the shapefile does not have a .prj file associated with it, dsc.spatialReference.name should return "Unknown". Check that the path to your data is referenced correctly.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your *.prj - perhaps that is missing a required item.

Comment: You have Name when it should be name - case sensitive.